# i'm doing a code but i don't see what i'm doing wrong. i keep getting this error 'ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2a'

Tags: python

```
def EnterRLE():
    Data=[]
    AmountOfLines = int(input("How many lines of RLE compressed data do you want to enter? "))
    if AmountOfLines >= 3:
        Lines = 1
        while Lines <= AmountOfLines:
            Data.append(input("Please enter the compressed data one line at a time: "))
            Lines=Lines+1


        for index in range (0,AmountOfLines):
            SubStr = Data[index]


            index=0

            for index in range (0,len(SubStr)):
                number = int(SubStr[index:index+2])
                character = SubStr[index+2]
                print ("numberpart is: ", number)
                print ("character is :", character)
                print (number*character)


EnterRLE()
```

Comment: Can you edit the program's input?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information so I assume that you have always 1 digit followed by 1 character in the string.

If your string `SubStr` starts with `'2a'` and `index` is `0` then `SubStr[index:index+2]` will give you `'2a'` and that can't be converted to an integer.

If you have 2 digits followed by 1 character in the string you'll get another problem. If your string `SubStr` starts with `'22a'` and `index` is `1` then `SubStr[index:index+2]` will give you `'2a'` again. You will have to increase the step you use for traversing the string.

I rewrote the code to make it more pythonic while assuming that you have always 1 digit followed by 1 character in the string. A fix for 2 digits is easy.

```
def enter_rle():
    amount_of_lines = int(
        input("How many lines of RLE compressed data do you want to enter? "))
    if amount_of_lines < 3:
        return

    data = []
    for _ in range(amount_of_lines):
        data.append(input("Please enter the compressed data one line at a time: "))

    for line in data:
        for index in range(0, len(line), 2):
            number = int(line[index])
            character = line[index + 1]
            print(f'numberpart is: {number}')
            print(f'character is : {character}')
            print(character * number)


enter_rle()
```

Answer (score 0):

> i'm doing a code but i don't see what i'm doing wrong.

What you are doing wrong is entering `2a` when prompted by `input("How many lines of RLE compressed data do you want to enter? ")` and passing the entered string to `int()` without validation.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand this correctly one line of your input is formatted like this:

```
[2 digit number][1 char][2 digit number][1 char] ...
```

One block consists of 3 characters, so you want your `index` to be incremented by 3 each round. To achieve that you can fix your for loop like this:

```
            for index in range (0, len(SubStr), 3):
```